# how to do sampling without knowing the signal frequency in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, frequency, sampling

I am currently doing research on nonuniform sampling method and use it to detect frequency of the signal. I want to simulate this situation using Matlab.

```
t = 0:1/2500:.25;
freq_cont = 3600;
cont_signal = cos(2*pi*freq_cont*t); %COntinous time signal of frequency 1600Hz
nu = 1: 1000;
xnu = cos(2*pi*(**freq**/1000)*nu);
```

In the above code continuous signal is being sampled but frequency has to be known. How do I perform sampling without knowing signal frequency in advance in Matlab?

Comment: To obtain a non-uniform sampling: pick a segment of the curve, perform polynomial curve fitting of increasing order until the approximation error is below a desired threshold, repeat for another segment. Then you could use the [Non-uniform discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform) for the frequency detection.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was answered in the following link:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25013/how-to-calculate-the-frequency-of-a-signal-without-knowing-the-sampling-frequenc

Basically you can't, but you can use relative frequencies.